# Running an API Request Every 15 Seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use an API that has been recently rate limited and requests have to be run every 15 seconds as that is the wait time otherwise a status code of 429 rate limit exceeded is returned.

I often have more than one email address that needs to be run against this API and the email addresses are contained within an array. How would I go about running the request every say 15.5 seconds but move onto each email address until the end of the array? It's a very tricky one for sure. I've tried:

```
setInterval(checkEmail(email), 15500);
```

No joy, for some reason that just doesn't seem to work. Btw should point out that I'm using a JQuery $.ajax() within that checkEmail(email) function.

Any ideas anybody?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you're limited to 1 request every 15 seconds, what are you going to do when you have multiple users making the request? You would probably be best to either pay to use the API (presuming you're on a free plan, hence the rate limit) or find an alternative

Comment: cron and serverside language, a little problem with cron , it only accepts minutes

Comment: It's a free API but unfortunately due to some very unkind people (always someone has to spoil things) the API started getting hammered big time and the guy had no choice but to set a rate limit on it. There is no paid version. If you must know it's the 'Have I been pwned' API by Troy Hunt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do the following:

```
var emails = [];   
var interval_id; 

function _start() {
    interval_id = window.setInterval(function() {
        var email = emails.shift();
        if (email) {
            var r=checkEmail(email.address);
            if (email.callback) email.callback(r);
        }
        else {
            window.clearInterval(interval_id);
        }
    }, 15500);
}

function add_email(email, callback) {
    emails.push({address:email, callback:callback});
    if (!interval_id) _start();
}
```

Whenever you have a new email address to check, just run `add_email(email)`. This will add it to the queue and start the interval timer if necessary. Additionally, you can say `add_email(email,function(result) {....})` if you want to get notified when the check is completed.